# Concurrency pattern equivalent to run once, wait for completion from all threads

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency

When converting a legacy code to new Concurrency framework, I discovered a few instances where the following pattern is used:

- A thread calls function with the closure as a parameter
- Function checks if some other function ("the actual work") is already running.

  - If yes, it will store the closure and do nothing else (so "the actual work" function does not run multiple times in parallel)
  - If no, it will instantiate another asynchronous function that does some actual work
- When the "the actual work" function completes, it will execute all callbacks that were stored while it was running.

A very simplified example:

```
class Test {

    private static let serial = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue")

    private var completions = [(Result<Void, Error>) -> Void]()

    private var isRunning = false

    func callMe(id: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {

        Test.serial.sync {

            print("\(id) called")
            completions.append(completion) // Preserve completion

            if !isRunning {
                print("\(id) is going to start doing something useful")
                isRunning = true
                doSomeAsyncStuff()
            }
        }
    }

    private func doSomeAsyncStuff() {

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {

            print("finished doing something useful")

            Test.serial.sync {
                self.isRunning = false
                self.completions.forEach { completion in
                    completion(.success(()))
                }
                self.completions.removeAll()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for example if I do this:

```
let test = Test()

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 3) { i in
    test.callMe(id: i) { _ in
        print("\(i) is done")
    }
}
```

I will get the expected output:

```
0 called
0 is going to start doing something useful
1 called
2 called
finished doing something useful
0 is done
1 is done
2 is done
```

that is "the actual work" function was executed once, and all callbacks executed after it was done.

Now, trying to convert this to new Concurrency. A naive implementation would be:

```
actor NewTest {
    
    private var isRunning = false
    
    func callMe(id: Int) async throws {
        
        print("\(id) called")
        
        if !isRunning {
            print("\(id) is going to start doing something useful")
            isRunning = true
            try await doSomeAsyncStuff()
        }
    }
    
    private func doSomeAsyncStuff() async throws {
        
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        print("finished doing something useful")
        self.isRunning = false
    }
}
```

However this obviously won't work: the first thread, which kicks off "the actual work" will suspend waiting for result, giving time for other threads to run. And since they are not waiting for anything, they will complete prematurely. Example:

```
let newTest = NewTest()

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 3) { i in
    Task {
        try await newTest.callMe(id: i)
        print("\(i) is done")
    }
}
```

The result will be:

```
2 called
2 is going to start doing something useful
1 called
1 is done
0 called
0 is done
finished doing something useful
2 is done
```

Not what I wanted obviously.
So far I only came up with the "hybrid" idea:

```
actor HybridTest {
    
    private var completions = [(Result<Void, Error>) -> Void]()
    
    private var isRunning = false
    
    func callMe(id: Int) async throws {
        
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) -> Void in

            callMe(id: id) { result in
                
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    continuation.resume()
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Back to old code
    private func callMe(id: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        print("\(id) called")
        completions.append(completion)
        
        if !isRunning {
            print("\(id) is going to start doing something useful")
            isRunning = true
            doSomeAsyncStuff()
        }
    }
    
    // Back to old code
    private func doSomeAsyncStuff() {

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {

            print("finished doing something useful")

            Task {
                await self.update(result: Result.success(()))
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func update(result: Result<Void, Error>) {
        isRunning = false
        completions.forEach { completion in
            completion(result)
        }
        completions.removeAll()
    }
}
```

But I wonder if there's a better way to achieve the same pattern.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: don’t mix GCD and the new Concurrency or completion handlers and the new Concurrency. When setup correctly an actor will not run 2 tasks at the same time unless you tell it to with something like a task group. You should always convert any old code with completion handlers using a Continuation.

Comment: Task group is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: @loremipsum "don’t mix GCD and the new Concurrency" - and I didn't. I'm using the proper tool (`withCheckedThrowingContinuation`) to bridge them (exactly as apple intended to). So it's an acceptable workaround (and apple used it btw in some of the demos as well). It's just not a proper solution - hence my question. Thanks for TaskGroup pointer, I will try it

Comment: You have `DispatchQueue` and `Task` you don't need `DispatchQueue` if you are using the new Concurrency it is a replacement. You also have `DispatchQueue` inside of an `actor`

Comment: @loremipsum In `doSomeAsyncStuff` of "hybrid" the `DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter` was used to demonstrate async behavior, it's not part of design (I thought it was pretty obvious?). In reality in this function there will be some network request, or a call to BT, or anything else that is not synchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal translation in Swift concurrency would entail saving a `Task`, which subsequent calls could `await`. This eliminates the need for the `isRunning` state variable (because if there is a `Task`, then it is running) as well as the array of closures (because multiple calls can `await` the same `Task`).

E.g., something along the lines of:

```swift
actor Test {
    var task: Task<Void, Never>?

    func callMe(id: Int) async {
        print("\(id) called")

        if let task {
            _ = await task.value
            return
        }

        task = Task {
            print("\(id) is going to start doing something useful")
            await doSomeAsyncStuff()
            task = nil
        }

        _ = await task?.value
    }

    func doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        print("finished doing something useful")
    }
}
```

And then:

```swift
func test() async {
    let test = Test()

    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for i in 0 ..< 3 {
            group.addTask {
                await test.callMe(id: i)
                print("\(i) is done")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That produces:

```
0 called
1 called
2 called
0 is going to start doing something useful
finished doing something useful
2 is done
0 is done
1 is done
```

---

FWIW, I have used a task group in lieu of `concurrentPerform` and a `Task.sleep` (which is a non-blocking “sleep”) instead of `dispatchAfter`. It is probably best to retire all GCD API, and remain within the realm of Swift concurrency.

---

For the sake of future readers, perhaps a more elegant solution is `AsyncSequence`, notably a `AsyncStream` with a `bufferingPolicy` of `.bufferingOldest`:

```swift
actor TestWithSequence {
    func iterate() async {
        for await value in sequence() {
            print("\(value) is going to start doing something useful")
            await doSomeAsyncStuff()
        }
    }

    private var block: ((Int) -> Void)?

    func sequence() -> AsyncStream<Int> {
        AsyncStream(bufferingPolicy: .bufferingOldest(1)) { contination in
            block = { value in
                contination.yield(value)
            }
            contination.onTermination = { _ in
                Task { await self.reset() }
            }
        }
    }

    func callMe(id: Int) async {
        print("\(id) called")
        block?(id)
    }
}

private extension TestWithSequence {
    func reset() {
        block = nil
    }

    func doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        print("finished doing something useful")
    }
}
```

Now, this does *not* address the OP‘s desire for subsequent calls to await the earlier `doSomeAsyncStuff`, but this does keep you in the world of structured concurrency (so cancelations are propagated automatically).

And, alternatively, you can use [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md), of the [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms) package, with a `.buffer(policy:)` of `.bufferingOldest`, which simplifies this even further, but still remaining with structured concurrency:

```swift
actor TestWithChannel {
    private let channel = AsyncChannel<Int>()

    func iterate() async {
        for await value in channel.buffer(policy: .bufferingOldest(1)) {
            await doSomeAsyncStuff(value)
        }
    }

    func callMe(id: Int) async {
        print("\(id) called")
        await channel.send(id)
        print("\(id) finished")
    }
}

private extension TestWithChannel {
    func doSomeAsyncStuff(_ value: Int) async {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        print("finished doing something useful with \(value)")
    }
}
```

With `AsyncChannel`, the caller will `await` the `for`-`async`-`await` loop to pick up the sent value, but it does not `await` the `doSomeAsyncStuff`. So again, this does not satisfy the OP’s desire to `await` that, but it is my “go to” pattern for buffered handling of an asynchronous sequence.